# should I retag a question that has specific tags for a general question

Tags: discussion, tags

Specifically this post [How to deal with old web site with security issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971833/how-to-deal-with-old-web-site-with-security-issues/4972047#4972047)

I have not retagged a question before, so wanted to get an opinion first. The user tagged it as asp.net and C# (since that's the language he's working in) However, I don't think it's really necessary in this case. What do you guys think? Should I retag it? I'm on the border

Comment: Are there other tags you think are more appropriate?  Or is it to just make the question more generic?

Comment: I was thinking about possibly applying some more tags if relevant. But at this point I was more focusing on the removed of unrelated tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the question about test tools or strategies might vary depending on the language. So I would be tempted to leave it alone, but I see the logic for changing it.  Most of the time when I retag it is actually the other way around I am adding specific tags where an asker just put "Java" and asked a GUI or a database question.